# does 0,7V supply on 5V devices damage the device?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply

In a certain state of my circuit there will be 0,7V on the supply pins of certain IC's ([comparator](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/608805.pdf) & [current sensor](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/64754.pdf)). Of course the IC's won't work on this voltage but does this damage the IC's or can I ignore it? The voltage is caused by a [diode](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/609324.pdf) (it's leaking some current probably) & a [dc-dc converter](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1599621.pdf).

Comment: It won't damage them.

Comment: @LeonHeller Unless you're feeding in a 5V signal into a chip powered by 0.7V...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no.

The supply voltage itself shouldn't cause any damage, no.  However, any signals being fed into the chips which are greater than 0.7V could cause damage.

For instance, many chips have input values listed in their datasheets as "\$V_{DD}+0.3V\$", which means that for chips like those, any voltage greater than 1V applied to its input pin when being powered from 0.7V will be out of specification and likely to cause damage.

So check the datasheets for your chips, and your circuit, to make sure that you're not going to fall foul of that.

Comment: I've always understood the "-0.3V < input < Vdd + 0.3V" spec to mean that the input protection diodes have a forward voltage drop of 0.3V, which is reasonable for a shottkey diode.  Exceed this input voltage, and you're actually powering the chip from the input pin instead of the intended power pin.  Whether that's a problem or not depends on the chip, the power circuit, and the input circuit.

Comment: @AaronD The most common effect is to burn out the ESD diodes which then leads to collateral damage around them, like destroying the input gate / pin.

Comment: Okay, so I got the mechanism right, and I figured that the failure mode would probably be something similar.  The ESD protection diodes are meant for very brief overloads, not (relatively) constant power, even if much lower than an ESD event.  It *might* be okay for very light system loads or an input that can't drive very much, but in most cases that's pushing your luck.

Comment: I've done analog input circuits with a series resistor (R1) followed by some over/undervoltage clamping diodes followed by another series resistor (R2) before finally reaching any active devices.  R1 protects my clamping diodes while R2 limits the current into the active device(s) if their internal diodes decide to turn on despite the clamps.  So far, so good.